# Can the mileage received from ethanol and gasoline be equalized?

Tags: gasoline, heat, mileage, ethanol

Is there technology to equalize the energy density of ethanol and gasoline? I found the below article about equalizing its calorific value.

[Have got the formula to equalize the calorific value of petrol and ethanol](https://www.thehindubusinessline.com/news/have-got-the-formula-to-equalise-the-calorific-value-of-petrol-and-ethanol-says-gadkari/article65353650.ece)

However, I need help locating additional articles and details about how the referenced Russian technology works.

Comment: Two things: 1) It sounds like a pig in a poke to me. Gasoline and ethanol have *very different* energy densities. Getting them near each other would make ethanol more like gasoline in composition. Just doesn't seem feasible or maybe if they are able to get it done, it's going to cost a lot more to get the ethanol there, making it fairly irrelevant. 2) Since this is new technology, you're not going to find anything out about it online. They are wanting to make money from this, I'm sure, so are not going to give away their trade secrets.

Comment: This looks like a spam seed.

Answer (score 1):

YES, and I have the formula!

> 1 ethanoliter = 1.54 standard liters

*Petrol will continue to be sold in standard liters, but ethanol will be sold in a new unit of volume called the ethanoliter, which is 1.54 standard liters. So now, with this new formula developed by Russian scientists, if you buy 20 liters of petrol or 20 ethanoliters of ethanol, both fuels will take you the same distance*.*

Of course this is utter nonsense. In the real world the energy available from burning ethanol ***is and will always be*** less than the energy from petrol. There is no formula. There is no magic. The article serves some purpose known only to Gadkari and his ministry.

Notice that the article was published in April of 2022, eight months ago, and claims that many vehicles in India will be running on flex fuel by now. Have you heard anything about that? Also the "green hydrogen" running silent cars in the "coming days." Where are the headlines about that?

The bottom line: **there is no magic formula**.

**The paragraph in italics above is intended to be satire and is not true.*

Comment: Science established baseline data. Gasoline has approximately 120,000 BTUs per gallon. Ethanol has approximately 76,000 BTUs per gallon. Basic chemistry. It can be difficult separating facts from fiction when searching online without basic academic skills.